# Include a wildcard in os.path.join() function to create a filepath

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to open an image file within a specific folder. I don't know how to explain the folder structure via code, so I'm illustrating it by levels
The folder structure are as follows:

```
level 1: data 
level 2: data\channel1                        data\channel2
level 3: data\channel1\morning                data\channel2\morning
             \channel1\evening                data\channel2\evening

level 4: data\channel1\morning\images.png     data\channel2\morning\images.png
         data\channel1\evening\images.png     data\channel2\evening\images.png

#where: 'images.png' are the image files
```

This is a simplified version but in actuality there are a lot of folder under the level 3 category. e.g. morning, evening, afternoon, midnight, etc. I want to extract the images without considering this 3rd level

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import pandas as pd:

root = os.getcwd()
img_file_loc = Path('data')
channels = ['channel1', 'channel2']
file_name = 'star.png'

temp = []
for channel in channels:
    img_file_path = os.path.join(root, img_file_loc, channel, '\\*\\', file_name)
    x = Image.open(img_file_path)
    temp.append(x)
```

I tried using a wildcard but it is giving me an error as below:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ...'\\*\\star.png'
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Consider the `fnmatch` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html or the `glob` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: The error is probably raised by `Image.open`, right? It expects one actual file path, it's not going to resolve your vagueness for you. You will need to use a function that interprets wildcards and then decide on one actual file from there, which you pass to `Image.open`.

Comment: Have a look at the `glob` library.  For example, it'll work something like: `files = glob.glob('/path/to/*')`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `rglob` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from pathlib import Path

img_file_loc = Path('path/to/data')
channels = ['channel1', 'channel2']
file_name = 'star.png'

for channel in channels:
    img_files = img_file_loc.rglob(file_name)
    for img_file in img_files:
        x = Image.open(img_file_path)
        temp.append(x)
```